# I cannot configure a way to start selenium on OSX from a startup LaunchD or startup cron

Tags: selenium, osx-yosemite, selenium-grid

I want to make my OSX Mac Mini start up the Selenium Jar (OSX Selenium Grid Node)  when the desktop is rebooted.  If I run the Selenium Jar with a logged in user account,  it runs perfectly.   When I run the Selenium Jar with the following:

1) Launchd

2) cron as user, with run cronjob on startup   (@startup)

I get an error on both the Safari and chrome if the jar is run without the user logging in.

There is a known defect (https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7933), but none of the workarounds worked.  Is there a way to run Selenium from a system startup when the user is not logged in?

command:

```
/usr/bin/java -jar /Applications/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role node -nodeConfig /Applications/selenium/node.json
```

Environment:

```
   OSX Yosemite

   Safari 8.0.3

   Chrome 41
```

Comment: Is this a problem specifically with Selenium, or just starting *any* executable jar on startup?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to run Selenium from a system startup when the user is not logged in?

**Answer**:  Kindof.

If your computer isn't logged in, how can you expect a Browser window to pop up?  Just picture your computer, at the login screen after boot.  you can't expect a browser window to pop up at the login prompt.

What you **can** do, is find out a way to automatically log in to the computer, then put your jar in a User Startup, rather than machine startup.

Another alternative, is if there is a way you can boot your mac just to command line, you can try headless.

Comment: Is this really an answer, or a comment?